# adding textmate theme for vim 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, themes, textmate

I'm trying to add textmate color theme to my vim editor

I have got the `railscast.vim` from https://github.com/jpo/vim-railscasts-theme and downloaded to

```
~/.vim/colors/railscast.vim
```

and in my `~/.vimrc` I have added the following line

```
colorscheme railscasts
```

and I dont have anything in `~/.vimrc.after` file

but still seems like the theme is not applied correctly (please look at the screenshot),

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or can anyone point me to a good resource

I'm using `vim version 7.2.411`

thanks in advance

Comment: What terminal are you using? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim might help.

Comment: Thanks I was able to fix the issue with support your link, If you could post the same as an answer I could accept it, thanks again :)

Comment: Glad that helped. Added an additional link to a color chart that helped get some colors in a guiless vim for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim) might help.

http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html, this helped as well for color customization using `cterm` option.